# How to create .certSigningRequest and .p12 file using fastlane

Tags: ios, certificate, fastlane

I created a new mobile provisioning profile and certificate using fastlane.

Found the certificate xxxxxxxx (iOS Distribution) which is installed on the local machine. Using this one.

"Creating new provisioning profile for 'xxxxxxxxx' with name 'xxxxxxxxxxx AppStore' for 'ios' platform".

So now i have to create the .certSigningRequest and .p12 for push Notification configuration. How do i do this using fastlane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pem`, another *fastlane* tool, to take care of your push notification profiles:
https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pem/

Running `fastlane pem` will:

- Create a new signing request
- Create a new push certification
- Download the certificate
- Generate a new .pem file in the current working directory, which you can upload to your server

Magic :)